# How to make the columns start from the center of the CSS Grid?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I'm trying to change my Flexbox layout to the new `display: grid`, And the columns are starting from the left by default.

[image]

How do I make them start from the center **without** specify the `grid-column-start` like this?

*(Just like the `align-items: center` in the Flexbox)*

[image]

Is it possible with the `display: grid`?

---

*Edit: Here are my HTML structure and the CSS style.*

HTML

```
<div class="centered grid">
    <div class="three wide column"></div>
    <div class="two   wide column"></div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
.grid
    display              : grid
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr)

.grid .column[class*="two wide"]
    grid-column: span 2

.grid .column[class*="three wide"]
    grid-column: span 3
```

And I also tried to apply the `justify-self: center` to the columns which I wanted to centered, but the result is not what I expected. (*The column doesn't start from the center of the grid.*)

[image]